# VS 2008: Code Analysis Tab Missing After Upgrade

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I just upgraded from VS 2008 Pro to VS 2008 Team System. I see "Run Code Analysis" in the build menu, but the project tab to alter the settings is missing.

Comment: Are you saying that the Code Analysis tab is missing from the project properties?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the deal. Once I removed the Code Contracts demo, the Code Analysis tab came back.